# Create Nuget Package, and include packages.config of each referenced project in same solution file

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, teamcity, nuget-package

I am sure it must have been asked before but I cannot find a concrete answer as yet.

I have a project called Testing.csproj that references to Testing.Hack.csproj

Testing.Hack.csproj has got a pacakges.config dependencies with three packages:

- MyPackage1
- MyPackage2
- MyPacage3

Now when I create a package Testing.csproj for publish, it is published successfully with IncludeReferencedProjects flag.

However, when I try to use Testing project functionality, Testing.Hack is complaining that it cannot find MyPackage1.dll.

How can I include the packages.config dependencies that are mentioned for Testing.Hack project.

I hope the question make sense.

Please note: I am using Team city build. However, it should not matter as the solution would do same on team city build step.

UPDATE:

I have tried by running a command without TeamCity and dependencies are identified.

The command that I have used is:

`nuget pack Testing.csproj -includereferencedprojects -output c:\localpackages`

I can see that it read packages.config for testing.csproj as well as testing.hack.csproj. However, the problem is with teamcity configuration and even though it has executed the same command but the output is not same.

I have also checked that my local nuget exe version is same as teamcity.

Comment: If "it shouldn't matter" I assume you've tried packaging with another tool such as [OctoPack ](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!